# Gamma Function Estimation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to show the numerical estimate $\Gamma(x) \leq 3x^x$ for $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$. I already know how to show $\Gamma(x) \leq x^x \leq 3x^x$ for $x \geq 1$. Therefore, it remains to show $\Gamma(x) = \int_0 ^\infty t^{x - 1} e^{-t} \,dt \leq 3x^x$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. My attempt is as follows, but it provides a constant that is greater than $3$:

Take $x \in [1/2, 1)$ and note $\Gamma(x) = \int_0 ^\infty t^{x - 1}e^{-t} \,dt = \int_0 ^1 t^{x - 1} e^{-t} \,dt + \int_1 ^\infty t^{x - 1} e^{-t} \,dt$. I will bound both integrals:

Note
$$
\int_0 ^1 t^{x - 1} e^{-t} \,dt \leq \int_0 ^1 \frac{1}{t^{1/2}} \,dt = 2.
$$
On the other hand, note that
$$
\int_1 ^\infty t^{x - 1}e^{-t} \,dt \leq \int_1 ^\infty e^{-t} \,dt = \frac{1}{e}.
$$
Knowing that $x^x \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we have $Cx^x \geq \frac{C}{\sqrt{2}} \geq 2 + \frac{1}{e} \approx 2.4$. This means that $C$ needs to be chosen as approximately $\sqrt{2} \times 2.4 \approx 3.4 > 3$.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe using $\Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x+1)/x$, where $x+1 \geq 1$, allows you to take advantage of what you’ve already proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough estimate is
$$
 \Gamma(x) < 2 < 3x^x 
$$
for $1/2 \le x \le 1$.

The left inequality holds because
$\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt \pi$ and $\Gamma(1) = 1$ are both less than $2$, and $\ln \Gamma(x)$ is a convex function.

The right inequality holds because $x \mapsto x^x$ is increasing for $x \ge 1/e$, so that
$$
 3x^x \ge 3 \left( \frac 12 \right)^{1/2} > 2
$$
for $x \ge 1/2$.